# Complex linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

For the linear transformation **y = Mx** where $$M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3+i\\0 & 1 & 2\\0 & 0 & 5-2i\\ \end{bmatrix}$$ Are the Domain and Codomain both $\Bbb{C^3}$ ($\Bbb{C}$ is all complex numbers)? Also what is the range?

Comment: the domain is $\mathbb{C}^3$, and I think codomain and range are the same thing and that is also $\mathbb{C}^3$

Comment: Well, the domain and codomain are whatever you define them to be when defining the function. The range is the set of all values $y$ such that there exists some $x$ in the domain such that $y=Mx$

Comment: In this case, the transformation is M: V1 -> V2, so as Piyush said, I think V1 and V2 are both $\Bbb{C^3}$

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your transformation is defined as 
$$T\begin{pmatrix} x \\y\\z\\ \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3+i\\0 & 1 & 2\\0 & 0 & 5-2i\\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\y\\z\\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x +2y+(3+i)z\\y+2z\\(5-2i)z\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
Its domain may not necessarilly be $\mathbb{C}^3$ but its range certainly is a subset of said set. This is because of the complex coefficients.

Now the size of the range can be obtained by row-reducing $M$. If there were any number of linearly independent rows, that would be the rank of $M$. Then the span of said vectors is the range you're looking for.

EDIT: For a quick check, try computing $\det(M)$. If it is non-zero, the range is the whole of $\mathbb{C}^3$.